# Should this question be moved?

Tags: discussion

[I'm referring to this one.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/98260/how-did-so-many-types-of-larvae-become-known-as-worms)

[Seems the English site is OK with getting it moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362135/on-which-site-are-questions-about-etymology-on-topic), unless someone here thinks otherwise. I think it is a good question, just needs to be asked at the right place.

Comment: FYI: I've down-voted this following the typical meta practice, which means "I disagree with the proposal" rather than "I think this is a bad question". I think your question is well-asked.

Answer (score 6):

I think moving a question with that many answers in place is not a good idea.

Typically, the only questions that are migrated are new, promising questions that are clearly out of place on one site and fit greatly at another. This question has a lot of overlap with Bio. In fact, I think the matter of popular language and scientific terminology is quite relevant for a site like this.

Answer (score 3):

It's entirely reasonable for a question to fit in more than one location on StackExchange, and both etymology and taxonomy have a lot of existing questions on this site.

The type of answers you get, however, will depend a lot on the particular site.

- Asked on Biology.SE, you're likely going to get more discussion of scientific taxonomy
- Asked on English.SE, you're likely going to get more discussion of literary usage

If the answers that you got here have satisfied you, then it seems just fine to stay here. If you want to know something more English-language focused, then rather than move the question (which might make the answers questionable for its new home), you could ask a follow-up question saying something like: "I asked [this question] over on Bio.SE and I learned about body shapes, but I'd like to know more about the dragons..."

Comment: Can you ask the same questions on multiple SE's for answers from different perspectives or is that frowned upon?

Comment: It's impolite to ask the same question in parallel, since that's likely to lead to duplicated effort on different sites. Instead, think about asking a series of questions. If the answers to a question leave you wanting more knowledge, then ask a followup that shows you've learned from the first. Depending on what you want to know, that followup might naturally fit on either the same site or a different site.

Comment: @Neil I think jake said it great, you can also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu for a broader discussion of cross-posting. IMO the three key things are: **write** a custom question per site, not a copy; **wait** between posting on more than one site, at least a week; **link** to other questions you've asked on the topic so people know what is already written and can avoid duplicating efforts.